# Checkbox values disappears in the gridview control whenever it redirects to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I having the page in that i have the gridview and page index changing also for every record i have

a check box.on top of the page i have the imagebutton in that when i click that button i am  redirecting it into another page 
in that page i have a back button which redirects to present page with checkbox and gridview.

what should i do to retain to get the checkbox when ever i check or some thing else?

This is gridview paging:

```
  protected void ManageCalenderShift_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    StoreOldValue();
    EmployeeDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    SortedBindDataToGrid();
    PupulateoldCheckValue();
}
private void StoreOldValue()
{
    ArrayList categoryIDList = new ArrayList();
    foreach (GridViewRow row in EmployeeDetails.Rows)
    {
        Label can_id = (Label)row.FindControl("UserACENumber");
        bool result = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("Chkgrid")).Checked;
        if (Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] != null)
            categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
        if (result)
        {
            if (!categoryIDList.Contains(can_id.Text))
                categoryIDList.Add(can_id.Text);
        }
        else
            categoryIDList.Remove(can_id.Text);
    }
    if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
        Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] = categoryIDList;
}
private void PupulateoldCheckValue()
{
    ArrayList categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
    if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in EmployeeDetails.Rows)
        {
            Label can_id = (Label)row.FindControl("UserACENumber");
            if (categoryIDList.Contains(can_id.Text))
            {
                CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("Chkgrid");
                myCheckBox.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the redirect to another page code that goes to page1:

```
protected void imgView_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    StoreOldValue();
    PupulateoldCheckValue();
    Response.Redirect("page1.aspx?UserACENumber=" + (Server.UrlDecode(URLSecurity.Encrypt(UserContext.ACENumber))));

}
```

then in the "page1" i have back button which redirects to "page" aspx :

```
 protected void imgimgBack_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("page.aspx?UserACENumber=" + (Server.UrlDecode(URLSecurity.Encrypt(UserContext.ACENumber))));
}
```

now my issue is:

when i check any one checkbox in the "page.aspx" and i go click image button and redirects to "page1.aspx" and come back to current working "page.aspx" whatever  the checkbox i have checked gets disappear.

Comment: Why are you redirecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do that manually.

[Maintaining State of CheckBox while Paging in GridView](http://blog.codovations.com/2009/02/maintaining-state-of-checkbox-in.html)

Comment: i am doing that one when i go to another page and come to present working page only i get this issue....

Comment: your saying  while maintaining the check box state while paging...i know that .....my issue is when check any checkbox....and then click the image button and go to the page and come back to pervious page it disappears.....what i have checked

Comment: its because you need to store the state of the checkboxes in DB and the restore them in page load when user comes back to the page after navigating away from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your GridView is being Re-built when the page loads when you are navigating from the other page.

The best way to maintain what Checkboxes have been checked through out the whole gridview and different pages is to save these values in a database/storage of some sort. That way when you are binding the GridView, you can set up the Checkbox values accordingly.

Another way would be to add some Page Caching to the page which holds the GridView, however I am not sure this would be the best solution when you have Pagination involved.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read a CheckBox doesn't use ViewState to retain its state. It used the content of  HTTP POST to determine whether or not to set the control as Checked.

So a solution would be to persist the checked values in the database/session etc. and then rebind them when the page loads again.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using Server.Transfer here. I think that you can still access the viewstate of the page that way.